# Combo box with store and text embed when load and listeners in extjs4?

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

the below Ext JS code works fine. the combo box load the phone number properly when i edit the grid. But i need the text to display clear/delete with phone numbers in combobox. When i click clear/delete i need to add some functionality.

the combo box looks like looks like as follows:

```
Clear/Delete
121-224432133
123-344545353
666-323231231
423-4324442344
```

.
.
.

### ExtJS code:

```
{ xtype: 'gridcolumn', header: 'Phone#',  width: 100, dataIndex: 'PhoneNumber',
editor: {
         xtype: 'combo',
         typeAhead: true,
         triggerAction: 'all',
         selectOnTab: true,
         store: App.mcmAllAgentsStore,
         typeAhead: true,
         emptyText : 'Clear/Delete',
         displayField: 'PhoneNumber',
         valueField: 'Agent',
         queryMode: 'local',
         listeners: {
                scope: this,
            specialkey: function(f, e) {
            if(e.getKey() === e.ESC) {          this.hide(); }
                                        }   
                                    }
                       }
                },
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should turn this boring combo box into a mighty [GridPicker](https://github.com/rixo/GridPicker)! Check the [last example](http://planysphere.fr/ext/GridPicker/examples/) in particular.

Comment: is there no way rather than GridPicker

Comment: You could theoretically render a top toolbar into the combo list component by mimicking the code already present for the paging toolbar... I have been able to so something similar in Ext3 but never managed to have it lay out correctly in Ext4. Another option would be to add "virtual" records to the combo but that isn't straightforward either. The question has already been asked here, and I saw only partial answers.

Comment: @rixo.. can you give example in Jsfiddle